# Spring Boot: Configuring AuthenticationManager with custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application, I am using JWT and a custom `UserDetailsService`. My `AuthenticationManager` is configured in a class annotated with `@Configuration` using the following method:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .and()
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Even though I specified a `UserDetailsService`, I am faced with the following problem: When my `JWTLoginFilter` intercepts the login request, and `getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token)`
 is called, I get the following exception:

```
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'butler-test.users' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.kehrbusch.butler.apigate.jwt.JWTLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication(JWTLoginFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'butler-test.users' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:776)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'butler-test.users' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:692)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Setting a query using `usersByUsernameQuery(query)` on my `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` solves this problem, but is this the only solution? Shouldn't the `UserDetailsService` provide the information needed to retrieve the `UserDetails` for a username?

In case it helps, here is a snippet from the `JWTLoginFilter`:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    AccountCredentials credentials = new ObjectMapper().readValue(httpServletRequest.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}
```

This is my user entity (there are subclasses for specific users):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "u_userdetails")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BasicUser implements UserDetails {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -109962402457721028L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using=LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "registration_date")
    private LocalDate registrationDate;

    @Column(name = "locked")
    private boolean locked;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "activation_key")
    private String activationKey;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "u_user_group", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Group> groups;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="u_user_role", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    @Column(name="role")
    private List<String> roles;

    protected BasicUser() {}

    public BasicUser(
            @JsonProperty("id") UUID id, 
            @JsonProperty("username") String username,
            @JsonProperty("password") String password, 
            @JsonProperty("registrationDate") LocalDate registrationDate,
            @JsonProperty("locked") boolean locked, 
            @JsonProperty("enabled") boolean enabled,
            @JsonProperty("activationKey") String activationKey,
            @JsonProperty("email") String email,
            @JsonProperty("roles") List<String> roles) {
        this.id = id; 
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.activationKey = activationKey;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String role : roles) {
            res.add(new BasicGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public LocalDate getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getAuthorities(roles);
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getActivationKey() {
        return activationKey;
    }

    public void setActivationKey(String activationKey) {
        this.activationKey = activationKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the entity class look like for `butler-test.users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong. You defined 2 authentication mechanisms, one is a *user details service*, and the second is a *JDBC authentication*.

In order to authenticate a user you only need one kind of mechanism to do that.

Your JVM "complains" about a bad SQL grammar, and if you'll examine the exception more closely you'll see that in particular JVM "complains" that he can't find the `users` table in your DB.

It seems that your JDBC authentication kicks in and tries to find the user credentials in the `users` DB table.

When you use this kind of authentication (JDBC) that is where and how Spring will try to authenticate the users, by trying to find a matching record within the `users` table in your DB.

You obviously mixing 2 authentications mechanisms by trying to read from:

```
@Table(name = "u_userdetails")
```

**If you want to use JDBC authentication make sure to read the credentials from `users` table.**

**And not from**:

```
@Table(name = "u_userdetails")
```